# Flask_WTF csrf decorator attribute error

Tags: javascript, ajax, flask, flask-wtforms

I am using flask_wtf to protect web pages which are not forms, but which post Ajax data from JavaScript.

I am getting a 'AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'error_handler'' for the '@csrf.error_handler' decorator and can't work out why.

on the Flask server:

```
from flask_wtf import csrf
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(config)
csrf.CsrfProtect(app)

@csrf.error_handler
def csrf_error(reason):
    return render_template('404.html', reason=reason)

@app.route('/completed/')
def completed(results, methods=['POST']):
    data = str(request.form['data'])
```

JavaScript:

```
function sendAjax(data){
    //@param data: JSON stringified object
    var csrfToken = document.getElementsByName("csrf_token").getAttribute("content");
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('PUT', '/completed');
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    xhr.onload = function() {
        if (xhr.status === 200) {
            var userInfo = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        }
    };
    xhr.send(data);
}
```

html:

```
<!-- 'form' with hidden field just so can post data back to server -->
<form method="post" action="{{ url_for('completed') }}">
    <meta id="csrf_token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to associate the error handler with your instance of `CsrfProtect`.

```
from flask_wtf.csrf import CsrfProtect

app = Flask(__name__)
csrf = CsrfProtect(app)

@csrf.error_handler
def csrf_error(reason):
    return render_template('404.html', reason=reason)
```